# python postgis ST_Contains failing query

Tags: python, postgis

I have been trying the following but always fails,

```
roomTypeSQL = "SELECT spftype FROM cameron_toll_spatialfeatures WHERE ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText(%s), ST_geomFromWKB(geometry)) = 'True';"
roomTypeData = (pointTested) # "POINT(-3.164005 55.926378)"
.execute(roomTypeSQL, roomTypeData)
```

I want to get the polygon from my table which contains the specific point. I have also tried `ST_Within` which also fails. I think my problem is related to the formatting of the point and polygon but I have tried almost all combinations and nothing does the job. I tried defining my polygon and it worked but I must do it with a polygon from the database. My postgresql log file is not particularly helpful either..
Can anybody see anything going wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had to do with python operators. I entered all the sql arguments using the python % operator properly and it worked. Like this,

```
roomTypeSQL = "SELECT spftype FROM cameron_toll_spatialfeatures WHERE ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText(%s),ST_geomFromWKB(geometry))=%s;"

roomTypeData = (pointTested,'t') # "POINT(-3.164005 55.926378)"

.execute(roomTypeSQL, roomTypeData)
```

The python operator can be quite frustrating sometimes. It doesn't always work as expected. I have some examples of SQL commands in which I had to place the arguments directly inside SQL commands. This method worked although its not advisable in Python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

might be a simple answer...st_contains returns 't' not 'true'.  Postgres is cap sensitive, make sure t not T